# How does CXF translate WSDL's localhost to actual server URL?

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, cxf, wsdl2java

All WSDLs I have seen so far, use **localhost** to describe the services address. e.g.:

```
<wsdl:service name="SQLService">
  <wsdl:port name="SQLServiceSoap" binding="tns:SQLServiceSoap">
     <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/rservice/services/SQLServiceSoap" />
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

But when the **client** of such service is run, it *somehow* knows where the real URL of that service, even if run on a **remote** machine!

How does CXF perform this "magic"?

IOW, how does the client JAR on a test machine which **is not** the machine on which the service runs, know where that server is and its address?

I `grep`-ed the source code and `strings`-ed the client's jar file and found no trace whatsoever to the server's URL.

So how does that work?

**UPDATE**: In my super natural detective efforts, I just found a file named `config.xml` in the directory where the **client's** JAR file is located. That `config.xml` contains the actual server's URL. So it appears that this is how this is done in the particular case of the project I inherited.

Now the question(s) is:

1. Is this the **standard** way of doing this?
2. Is there a standard (or recommended way) at all in CXF?
3. Or is it pretty much left to the developer to decide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, the web service will have a production URL and a test/QA/UAT URL.  The developer will develop against the test URL, and then once it's ready for production he will switch the URL to point to production.

It is up to the developer to decide how this is accomplished and there is no standard way of handling it.